# str_replace() only to find exact match

Tags: php

I want to replace the exact match using `str_replace()`.

My code:

```
$html = array("<br>", "<b>", "</b>", "<i>", "</i>");
$custom = array("--", "*", "**", "\\", "\\\\");

$arr = str_ireplace($custom, $html, $arr);
```

But if the original string is `hello *this** should be bold` then it replaces each `*` sign with `<b>`:

```
hello <b>this<b><b> should be bold
```

Instead of how I want it to look:

```
hello <b>this</b> should be bold
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good application for [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) as it will replace in order of longest substring first:

```
$html = array("<br>", "<b>", "</b>", "<i>", "</i>");
$custom = array("--", "*", "**", "\\", "\\\\");
$arr = 'hello *this** should be bold';
echo strtr($arr, array_combine($custom, $html));
```

Output:

```
hello <b>this</b> should be bold
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AGKNX)

Comment: You are something+1:

Comment: Very nice! What if `$arr` was an array with multiple texts? How could I loop through it and do this to each key value?

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström see this demo: https://3v4l.org/jmCNe (note you need to pass the array element by reference in the foreach to change it)

Comment: @Nick Thanks, that did it perfectly! :)